# Postfix virtual domains and Cyrus for imap

Tags: centos, postfix, email-server, imap, cyrus

I am setting up a email server on a centos box where I am using the virtual(8) delivery agent within postfix so that I dont need to create a unix user for each email address, and I have set up Cyrus with sasl auth to handle imap. essentially I have gotten to a point in the process where there are two distinct inboxes for each address--One Postfix, and one Cyrus. I have experimented with symlinking them together, however the naming conventions for new messages do not match between the two so I am not sure how to "combine them" so to speak.

Some info from my config files:

```
[root@mail ~]# cat /etc/imapd.conf
virtdomains:        userid
defaultdomain:      domain.com
servername:     mail.domain.com
configdirectory:    /var/lib/imap
partition-default:  /var/spool/imap
admins:         cyrus
sievedir:       /var/lib/imap/sieve
sendmail:       /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
hashimapspool:      true
allowanonymouslogin:    no
allowplaintext:     yes
sasl_pwcheck_method:    auxprop
sasl_mech_list:     CRAM-MD5 DIGEST-MD5 PLAIN
tls_cert_file:      /etc/pki/cyrus-imapd/cyrus-imapd.pem
tls_key_file:       /etc/pki/cyrus-imapd/cyrus-imapd.pem
tls_ca_file:        /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt

autocreatequota:        -1
createonpost:           yes
autocreateinboxfolders:     spam
autosubscribeinboxfolders:  spam 

[root@mail ~]# tail /etc/postfix/main.cf

smtpd_helo_required             = yes 

virtual_mailbox_domains = domain.com
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/mail/mailboxes
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmailbox
virtual_minimum_uid = 100
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_alias_maps      = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

As of right now, email sent locally on the box goes to the adresses cyrus inbox, which is somewhere within /var/spool/imap/domain, and mail coming from external machines is going to the posfix inbox at /var/mail/mailboxes. So just not sure how to put them together, any advice would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Youre are looking for virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:/var/lib/imap/socket/lmtp see evt. 
[http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Postfix+CyrusImapd+SASL#head-c104e8c1d1b57266ced18db9e2b4022a11080b9](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Postfix+CyrusImapd+SASL#head-dc104e8c1d1b57266ced18db9e2b4022a11080b9)